How to change the URL of button after it is sent
I have a bot which will send approximately 30 different messages with different InlineKeyboardButtons; each one of these buttons will point to a different URL. As each of the URLs is generated by a relatively time consuming process (that I an unable to speed up), and generally only one of the 30 buttons will be clicked, I would like to call the function to generate the URL only if the button is actually clicked AND have the URL open on the client device.
Function to get the URL, which functions independently without issue:
def get_url(input):
    ...
    return URL

Attempted to use webbrowser as well, which does not open the URL on any machine/device using telegram, but functions independently without issue:
def get_url():
    ...
    webbrowser.open(url)

Using this keyboard button calls the function and generates the URLs on creation of the button at send time, which is lengthy:
InlineKeyboardButton('URL', url=get_url(input))

Using this keyboard button does not generate the URLs at send time, but I am unable to open a browser, but it does call the function as desired:
InlineKeyboardButton('IMDB', callback_data=1)

Any guidance on how I can generate the URLs and open a browser window only if a user clicks the button, and not generate all the links at initial send time?

only idea: use url to own web server which will generate target url and it will use HTTP response with code 30x to redirect browser to new page. OR it will send HTML with tag <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://target_url">. OR it will send HTML with JavaScript which will redirect to target url.
